# KnockOut.js in HTML <!-- ko if: $root.valueA || $root.valueB --> NOT Working with OR '||'

Tags: html, knockout.js

I want to show a HTML paragraph based on a condition. This is working when I have only one. But, is now working when I use || operand.
Any help would be appreciated.
New to js - forgive if I am missing something.

```
<!-- ko if: $root.valueA || $root.valueB -->
 <p>
    Show this message.
 </p>
 <!-- /ko -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `valueA` and `valueB` are observables, you need to manually unwrap them:

```
<!-- ko if: $root.valueA() || $root.valueB() -->
```

Comment: They are observables from a different model for eg like below $root.AViewModel().valueA

In this case when I use || its not working for me. 
But, when I use only 1 condition without || its working.

Comment: I want to know how OR condition works in KO js

Comment: @Cyrus "||" is the right way to do an OR condition, the issue is the way KO interprets the rest of it. With just one condition it tests if it's an observable or computed, and unwraps it if so. But in instances like this you have to specify you want the result of the observable. So your example in the comment above, something like "$root.AViewModel.valueA() || $root.AViewModel.valueB()" is what you're looking for.